# Sidekiq worker is leaking memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, sidekiq, git-tf

Using the sidekiq gem - I have sidekiq worker that runs a process (git-tf clone of big repository) using IO.popen and tracks the stdout to check the progress of the clone.

When I am running the worker, I see that sidekiq memory is getting larger over the time until I get kernel OOM and the process get killed. the subprocess (java process) is taking only 5% of the total memory.

How I can debug/check the memory leak I have in my code? and does the sidekiq memory is the total of my workers memory with the popen process? 
And does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

**EDIT** 
This is the code of my worker - 
https://gist.github.com/yosy/5227250

**EDIT 2** 
I ran the code without sidekiq, and I have no memory leaks.. this is something strange with sidekiq and big repositories in tfs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find the cause for the memory leak in sidekiq, but I found a away to get a way from sidekiq.

I have modified git-tf to have server command that accepts command from redis queue, it removes lot of complexity from my code.

The modified version of git-tf is here:
https://github.com/yosy/gittf

I will add documentation later about the sever command when I will fix some bugs.